# How I can use use WSO2 IS from JAGERRYJS

Tags: jaggery-js, wso2-identity-server

I have seen various documentation but I can not entneder as "WSO2 IS" is used for "Jaggeryjs". I want to do something like what he does "WSO2 AppFactory" when you enter "edit codec"

Answer (score 0):

There is dashboard jaggery application that is shipped with Identity Server by default. This jaggery application has capabilities to invoke identity server API and do SSO with Identity Server.  You can access the dashboard by pointing browser to `https://{hostname}:{port}/dashboard/`  Also you can find the  jaggery application following location `<IS_HOME>\repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps`

I hope this would be helpful